# Typescript compiling different for team members

Tags: typescript, bitbucket

In our shared bitbucket solution, we have a typescript file that compiles correct for one developer, but wrongly for the two other developers. We suspect some sort of setup error.

When compiling we get the errors "(TS) Expression expected" and  "(TS) ':' Expected". In lines of code similar to this:

```
            item = item.replace("{customer}", "" + x.a_ticket?.CustomerId?.Name);
```

Note that this is most likely not a coding error, since it works for one developer. And when he published, it fixes the bug i the application, whereas if those of us who get the compileerror break the application when we publish.

Also the code has not been changed prior to the occurence of the error. We have all synced, and all code and nuget packages are the same.

We are unsure where to proceed to solve this, any tips and help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you have different versions installed. Make TypeScript a development dependency of your project and compile using the project local version.

Comment: I guess, the reason is `a_ticket?.Customer...` this syntax is called 'optional chaining' and supported since typescript 3.7. There seem to be some issues with your setup, e.g. it sounds as if you would push "compiled" javascript to git instead of typescript sources only. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

Comment: Thank you fellas. We will look in these directions